# Finding root for the segment - found the formula but it doesn't work for some values - wrong formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, roots, arithmetic-functions

I have the segment, defined as $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$.

### I know that $y_1\ge  0$ and $y_2 < 0$.

I want to compute the root point for that segment.

I decided to do it that way:

```
we know that:
```

$(x_2-x_1)(y-y_1) = (y_2-y_1)(x-x_1)$

```
after some operations:
```

$y = \frac{(y_2-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)}x + \frac{-x_1\cdot y_2 + x_2\cdot y_1}{x_2-x_1}$

So simply, I get the line as $y = ax + b$ where:

$a = \frac{(y_2-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)}$

$b = \frac{-x_1\cdot y_2 + x_2\cdot y_1}{x_2-x_1}$

To compute root point, I just compute $f(0)$, which is equal to $b$ in my example (for $y_1 \ge  0$ and $y_2 < 0$):

$y_0 = \frac{-x_1\cdot y_2 + x_2\cdot y_1}{x_2-x_1}$

I tested my solution for:

$(x_1, y_1) = (1, 2)$

$(x_2, y_2) = (4, -1)$

```
RESULT: 3
```

And it's ok. But for:

$(x_1, y_1) = (4528, 498)$

$(x_2, y_2) = (5527, -1500)$

```
RESULT: 9554
```

Which is **WRONG**. The root point of segment from $x_1$ to $x_2$ ($y_1 \ge  0$ and $y_2 < 0$) cannot be **after** $x_2$.

**So is my formula wrong?**

Comment: What do you mean with "root point of a segment"? Anyway what you did does not work in the case $x_1=x_2$...

Comment: I mean the root point for the line that contains the segment ($x_1$,$y_1$ $x_2$,$y_2$). Precisely: the x value for the point of that line where y = 0. And anyway, I wrote that $y_1$>=0 and $y_2$<0 so $x_1$ is NEVER equal $x_2$ (same point does not have two y values)

Comment: Than it is not $b$, $b$ is the $y$ of the point where $x=0$.

Indeed, given the line $y=ax+b$, the intersections with the axis are given by the points $(0,b)$ and $(\frac{-b}{a},0)$.

Please note that *not* every line can be written in that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in the reasoning. Your equation is $y=a x + b$. Since you want $y=0$ and you look for $x$, then $$x=-\frac{b}{a}=\frac{{x_2} {y_1}-{x_1} {y_2}}{{y_1}-{y_2}}$$

Comment: You are welcome. This is the kind of mistakes I did loooong time ago and they were making me just crazy. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

$b$ should be

\begin{equation*}
b=-\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}x_{1}+y_{1}=\frac{-x_{1}y_{2}+x_{1}y_{1}}{%
x_{2}-x_{1}}+y_{1},
\end{equation*}

because from

\begin{equation*}
(x_{2}-x_{1})(y-y_{1})=(y_{2}-y_{1})(x-x_{1})
\end{equation*}

we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
y-y_{1} &=&\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1}) \\
&\Leftrightarrow &y=\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1})+y_{1} \\
&\Leftrightarrow &y=\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}x-\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{
x_{2}-x_{1}}x_{1}+y_{1} \\
&\Leftrightarrow &y=ax+b,\qquad a=\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}},b=-\frac{
y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}x_{1}+y_{1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

ADDED in response to OP's comment. For $(x_{1},y_{1})=(4528,498),(x_{2},y_{2})=(5527,-1500)$ we have $a=-2$ and 
$b=9554$. So

\begin{equation*}
y=-2x+9554
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
-2x+9554=0\Leftrightarrow x=4777.
\end{equation*}

Comment: I see and agree with transformations. But when I use the values $(x_1,y_1) = (4528,498), (x_2,y_2) = (5527,−1500)$ the calculated $b = -\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}x1+y1 = 9554$ (same as in my formula). So what's wrong now? The $x_0$ must be between 4528 and 5527, not 9554.

Comment: @PolGraphic See my edit to add the computation of $x_0=4777$.

Comment: Just checked it, and yes, again my mistake. Anyway I marked Claude Leibovici's respond as answer, because he first showed me the place where I was wrong. Sad thing that I cannot mark two answers, but I have voted up your post. Thank you for help :)

Comment: Glad to help! Your first mistake was in the computation of $b$.